# Fully-qualified import path in auto-generated code

Tags: go, import, swagger, swagger-codegen

## My problem

My apologies if the problem is trivial - I'm fairly new to golang, and want to understand the imports mechanism. I use OSX and simple go programs compile and work well.

I've generated a golang server using [automatic code generator](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) in the [swagger editor](http://editor.swagger.io/#/). I've unzipped the code into some directory in `/tmp/`, and the resulting server contains the following `main.go` file:

```go
package main

import (
        // WARNING!
        // Change this to a fully-qualified import path
        // once you place this file into your project.
        // For example,
        //
        //    sw "github.com/myname/myrepo/go"
        //
        sw "./go"
        "log"
        "net/http"
)

func main() {
        log.Printf("Server started")

        router := sw.NewRouter()

        log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
}
```

As expected from the comments, `go build main.go` Fails with the following error:

```
main.go:11:2:
go/default.go:3:1: expected 'IDENT', found 'import'
```

## Forensics

### The directory tree of the project

```
/tmp/goserver/go-server-server
├── LICENSE
├── api
│   └── swagger.yaml
├── go
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── app.yaml
│   ├── default.go
│   ├── logger.go
│   └── routers.go
└── main.go
```

### `go/default.go`

```
package

import (
    "net/http"
)

type Default struct {

}

func QuestionimagePost(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
}
```

## What have I tried

- Read about [go packages](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/imports)
- Tried to understand the package / import relationship in some github projects
- Moved the directory tree to `$GOPATH/src`, and changed the import to `sw "sw/go-server-server/go"`, which still gives `main.go:13:2:
  go/default.go:3:1: expected 'IDENT', found 'import'`

**What should be the fully-qualified import path of the `sw` import, and what does it mean?**

Comment: Never try to use relative imports paths (except maybe for throwaway examples). Imports are very simple, it's just the path to the module from `$GOPATH/src/`

Comment: So what should I do? Copy the folder the `$GOPATH/src/`?

Comment: The error looks like you have a file in the go directory named default.go that has syntax error(s).

Comment: @reedobrien Thanks, added the content of the file. Is it a missing package name problem? Is it related to the directory name? https://golang.org/doc/code.html#PackageNames

Comment: It is common to use the name of the directory a file is in as the name of the package. However using `package go` seems very confusing. `main` is a special package name used to indicate there is a main function in the package that is compiled to an executable  binary.

Comment: there is no name for the package in the code you posted. that is a syntax error. 
`package go
import "net/http"
...
`
would be correct but I personally would avoid using go as the package name or the directory name.

Answer (score 2):

The following did the trick:

- Adding a package name to all .go files in the go folder (I used `blah`)

eg. in go/routers.go

```
package blah

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func Logger(inner http.Handler, name string) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        start := time.Now()

        inner.ServeHTTP(w, r)

        log.Printf(
            "%s %s %s %s",
            r.Method,
            r.RequestURI,
            name,
            time.Since(start),
        )
    })
}
```

Do the same for `go/logger.go` and, in your case, `default.go`

- Following an `go/routers.go:7:2: cannot find package "github.com/gorilla/mux"` error, `go get 'github.com/gorilla/mux'`

Comment: can you elaborate on what "adding a package name" means?

Comment: @JHowIX I edited the answer to show what worked for me.  I think he means Adding a package name to all the .go files in the go folder.

Comment: i.e. routers.go, logger.go, and default.go

Answer (score 1):

You need to export some path as the `GOPATH`, say `$HOME/go`. 
`export GOPATH=$HOME/go`.

Then you can put your project in `$GOPATH/src/go-server-server` (`$HOME/go/src/go-server-server`) and your fully qualified path would be `go-server-server/go` if I am reading everything correctly.